# one lib multiple apps, how to easy update them all on android market place

Tags: android, google-play

I have one library for multiple apps, all of these apps will be in the marketplace in future.
So I was wondering if there was an easy way or even a way to update all these apps when I make changes to my Library. Instead of updating them al manualy.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it cant be done.